# Bind pair of array element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 8 values in an Array. I am trying to bind two values in a row. Next two in next row and vice versa. But I couldn't do that in `*ngFor`. Please help me out.

**TS**

```
times = ["7.00 AM","8.00 AM","10.00 AM","11.00 AM","1.00 PM","2.00 PM","4.00 PM","5.00 PM"]
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let time of times">
<button class="btn btn-outline">{{time}}</button>
</div>
```

But, displays one in each.

**Expected output**

[image: O/P]

Comment: split them in an array ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use index to get the next value in the array

```html
<div *ngFor="let time of times; let i = index;">
  <button
    *ngIf="times[i + 1]"
    class="btn btn-outline"
  >{{time}} - {{times[i + 1]}}</button>
</div>
```